# Too bright / Saturated when Inspecting Acer Iconia B1-A71 with Devtools on windows

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm inspecting Tablet Acer Iconia B1-A71 on windows with chrome. Everything seems to work nice, beside the colors show on windows. They seem too bight/oversaturated like shown on the printscreen above:
[image]

I did test with an android phone, and it looks good. I tried locating a firmware update on acer suport but couldn't find any firmware updates. Any idea what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try OTA Updates . might you are lucky . other option is install custom roms which is not recommended . by the way what is the current version of your tablet ?